# Is this a correct use case for AtomicReference in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have a processor cache class which is a singleton and has a `Processor` field. The `Processor` field will be set by a single `Updating` thread and used by many `Worker` threads.

I don't know whether my current implementation is a appropriate usage of the `AtomicReference`. Would you please check and correct it? In addition, can I just use the `volatile` instead of the `AtomicReference` in this case?

The implementation:

```java
class Cache {
    private AtomicReference<Processor> processor;

    public static getInstance() { ... }

    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor.get();
    }

    public void setProcessor(Processor old, Processor new) {
        processor.compareAndSet(old, new);
    }
}

/* Only one thread will update the processor cache */
class UpdatingThread {
    private Processor oldProcessor;

    public void run() {
        // some logic
        Processor newProcessor = createNewProcessor();
        Cache.getInstance().setProcessor(oldProcessor, newProcessor);
        oldProcessor = newProcessor;
        // some more logic
    }
}

/* Multiple workers will use the processor */
class WorderThread {
    public void run() {
        // some logic
        Processor processor = Cache.getInstance().getProcessor();
        // more logic using the processor
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your code _works,_ this sort of question is better-suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: This is not the actual code. I just don't know an appropriate usage of the `AtomicReference`. So the code is just a use case I made by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only thing you actually do is re-assign the `processor` field in the `Cache` class, a `volatile` field would be better suited. You do not use the extra features the `AtomicReference` provides.

Besides, if you do want to use `AtomReference` you should just use the `set` method so that you don't have to keep track of the `oldProcessor`.

Comment: So can I say that the `volatile` keyword makes the reference assignment atomic?

Comment: @is.magl yes, that is exactly what volatile does, as well as making assignments visible to other threads

Comment: To correct myself, reference assignment is always atomic, volatile makes assignment guaranteed visible between threads